# SQL lifting constraint of the WHERE clause on a specific result

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way of using the SELECT statement in a way that one of the selected datasets ignores the WHERE condition?

```
SELECT employee, employee(same data, but excluded) FROM table WHERE company IN ('company1','company2') (...);
```

It's intended to see total number of employees, their companies and the percentage of employees overall in the industry.

Comment: BTW, you SELECT from a _table_, not from a database.

Comment: The WHERE clause has already been "executed" when the SELECT list is taken care of.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional logic:

```
SELECT something,
       (case when (conditions) then something end) as excluded_something
FROM database ;
```

Comment: Still takes the WHERE clause into consideration. I know it would be simpler with 2 queries but unfortunately has to be 1

Comment: @DanielKlas . . . There is NO `WHERE` clause, so your comment does not seem to be referring to this answer.

Comment: Added the clause.

Comment: @DanielKlas . . . and that is not this answer.